# mongoose TypeError: Schema is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I've encountered a strange thing. I have several mongoose models - and in one of them (only in one!) I get this error:

```
TypeError: Schema is not a constructor
```

I find it very strange as I have several working schemas. I tried logging `mongoose.Schema` in the non-working schema and it is indeed different from the mongoose.Schema in my working schemas - how is that possible? The code is almost identical.
Here's the code for the non-working schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var errSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  images:[{
    type:String
  }],
  sizes:[{
    type: String
  }],
  colors:[{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Color'
  }],
  frontColors:[{
    type: Schema.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Color'
  }],
  script: Boolean
},{
  timestamps: true
});

var Err = mongoose.model('Err', errSchema);

module.exports = Err;
```

Code for a working schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var colorSchema = new Schema({
  name: String,
  image: String,
  rgb: String,
  comment: String,
});

var Color = mongoose.model('Color', colorSchema);

module.exports = Color;
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Of course!! Man, do I feel stupid! Thank you for your swift reply. Make an answer and I'll accept it :)

Comment: i am getting the same error, how did u resolve this ?

Comment: @vashishth - my problem came from a missing `Types` in `Schema.Types.ObjectId`. Once I added this, my problem disappeared.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `Schema.Types.ObjectId`, not `Schema.ObjectId`: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

Answer (score 19):

I have encountered the same thing. I have previous code like this

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var Schema = mongoose.Schema();
    var schema = new Schema({
        path : {type:string , required:true},
        title: {type:string , required: true}
    })
 module.export = mongoose.model('game', schema);
```

**Then I solved the constructor problem using below script**

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    var schema = mongoose.Schema({
        path : {type:string , required:true},
        title: {type:string , required: true}
    })
 module.export = mongoose.model('game', schema);
```

Comment: So, this technique worked for me also...but why? The official docs clearly show it in use as a constructor with `new` keyword. And, that is with simple data - not like above with the 'Objects stuff.' http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html

Answer (score 14):

The problem in my case was the export which should (s) at the end:

**Problem: missing (s) in exports**

```
module.export = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
```

**Solution: add (s) to exports**

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', EventSchema);
```

Answer (score 5):

I've solved this problem by importing Schema with upper case.

**Previous:**

```
const Scheme = mongoose.schema;
```

**After Fixing:**

```
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
```

**Full Schema:**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ItemSchema = new Schema({
    name : {
        type: String,
        required : true
    },
    date : {
        type : Date,
        default : Date.Now
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

Answer (score 2):

Understand am late to the Party, but the below code worked for me, could be helpful for someone using mongoose version 5.2.15

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Scheme = mongoose.Schema;

const ItemSchema = new Scheme({
    name: {
        type: String,
        require: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});

module.exports = Item = mongoose.model('Item', ItemSchema);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mongoose.Schema` instead of `let Schema = mongoose.Schema();`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue

previous code

```
module.export = mongoose.model('AllClassList', allClassListSchema);
```

correct code

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('AllClassList', allClassListSchema);
```

I was missing the "s" at the end of export

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who still has the error

1. Check your mongoose version on your package.json to see whether it's an older version
2. Re install it to a latest version

Worked for me!!

Answer (score 1):

I encounter this my solution is adding (s) in module.export, I forgot to add s in the end that's why it throw me that my Schema is not a constructor.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the issue
My previous code is like this :

```
const Mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Schema = Mongoose.Schema()  // here making Schema() like this is the issue
```

fixed code:

```
const Schema = Mongoose.Schema

   `

    const placeSchema` = new Schema({
        title: { type: String, required: true },
        description: { type: String, required: true },
        image: { type: String, required: true },
        address: { type: String, required: true }

module.exports = Mongoose.model('Place' , placeSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

connectDB(mongoURI); // database connection

// create schema 

    const student = new mongoose.Schema({
      name: String,
      workout: Boolean,
      height: Number,
    });
    
   // create model in students collections

    const Student = new mongoose.model("Student", student);
  
     // store data
    const adder = async () => {
   
      const ss = await Student.create({
        name: "jiya",
        workout: true,
        height: 6,
      });
    
    };
    

    //call function
    adder();
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this one with the help of *_Schema*

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const _schema  = mongoose.Schema;
//creat schema
const IdeaSchema = new _schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    details: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('ideas', IdeaSchema);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    username: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },
    password: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    profilePic: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

`const Mongoose = require('mongoose') const User = Mongoose.Schema({name: String})`
worked for me. replacing const mongoose with Mongoose

Answer (score 0):

This may seem trivial, but npm uninstalling and then reinstalling Mongoose worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me this error occurred due to wrong import in server.js file -

My mongoose.js file -

```
    const member = mongoose.Schema({
    id: Number,
    memberId: Number,
    name: String,
    contact: String,
    doj: String,
    plan: String,
    fees: Number
});

const Members = mongoose.model("Member", member);

const user = mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    password: String
});

const User = mongoose.model("User", user);

module.exports = Members;
module.exports = User;
```

And my server.js file import was -

```
const {Members, User} = require('./mongoose');
```

Fixed import -

```
const Members = require('./mongoose');
const User = require('./mongoose');
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked by changing:

```js
module.exports = { blog };
```

To:

```js
module.exports = blog;
```

Answer (score -1):

the problem was neither capitalization Schama nor forgetting "s" for export.
it was accidentally deleting: "('mongoose')" while I was codding!!!so I added it again! Problem solved!!

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```