# why I got this type error not a constructor for javascipt?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, constructor, postman

I am trying to create a new product.to test whether the result is sent to my mongodb , I input the values in postman.However , I am confused about this error.

> This is my Product file

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");


const ProductSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
    title: {type:String , required:true , unique:true},
    description: {type:String , required:true},
    img: {type:String , required:true },
    categories: {type: Array , required:true },
    size: {type:Array},
    color: {type:Array},
    price: {type: Number , required:true },
    inStock:{type:Boolean , default:true},

},
{ timestamps: true }
);

module.export = mongoose.model("Product" , ProductSchema);
```

> This is my post code

```
const router = require("express").Router();
const Product = require("../model/Product")
 //Create new product(testing in postman)
router.post("/", async (req,res)=>{
const newProduct = new Product(req.body);

try{
    const savedProduct = await newProduct.save();
    res.status(200).json(savedProduct);
}catch(error){
    res.status(500).json(error)
}
})
```

> After I send the values in postman, I always encounter this error.

```
TypeError: Product is not a constructor
```

Comment: Whatever `require("../model/Product")` returns is not a constructor. We've no way of telling what that is since you haven't provided a [mcve].

Comment: Depends what's in `../model/Product`, apparently not a Mongoose model

Comment: oh my bad I will edit now

Comment: Try `module.exports = mongoose.model("Product" , ProductSchema);`

Comment: Guys I add the Product file already

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65085639/13583510

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
module.export = mongoose.model("Product" , ProductSchema);
```

it should be

```
module.exports = mongoose.model("Product" , ProductSchema);
```